# http post not getting input into action field

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have a HTTP Post form that receives info from AngularJS (that takes it from the PHP BE).
I use the following code sample:

```
<form method="post" action="{{aw('TI.sup');}}">
<input type='hidden' name='bla' value="{{aw('TI.sup');}}" />
<input type="submit" class="button s-button"  value="bla" />
</form>
```

After page is loaded, I see the following result:

```
<form method="post" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
<input type="hidden" name="bla" value="https://thisis.the/url">
```

Strings without 'https:' work fine.

**Update**

The problem was with $sce, and has slightly changed after I Added a function to the controller.

now I'm getting:

```
<form method="post" action="https://thisis.the/url" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

**Update, take 2**

The form won't respond to submit because the previous URL was blank (before Angular changed it). I decided to take the info from PHP itself, but the following jquery will also do the trick:

```
$("#FormID").submit();
```

Thanks,

Dana.

Comment: Not clear what do you mean under `Strings without ':' work fine`

Comment: could you show the detail about what aw('TI.sup') do?

Comment: Why `action` changed to `class`? Are you sure you are talking about the same part in first and second code examples?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius the class is added by the formController

Comment: My bad, the problem was with Angular's $sce.
aw calls any variable or method from Angular to the view.

Comment: @wrdana Obviously, `https://thisis.the/url` is just an example url, what is the real server address?

Comment: @IlanFrumer The URL is https://direct.tranzila.com/. when I use <form method="post" action="https://direct.tranzila.com/"> it all works fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing a  [$sce:insecurl error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24interpolate%3ainterr?p0=%7B%7Baw%28%27TI.sup%27%29%7D%7D&p1=Error%3a%20%5B%24sce%3ainsecurl%5D%20http%3a%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.12%2F%24sce%2Finsecurl%3Fp0%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fthisis.the%252Furl) , probably because the action URL is from other domain/protocol.

#### From  [$sce:insecurl error docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24sce%3ainsecurl?p0=https%3a%2F%2Fthisis.the%2Furl):

> Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked
>
> ...
>
> To load templates **from other domains and/or protocols**, either adjust the whitelist/ blacklist or wrap the URL with a call to $sce.trustAsResourceUrl.

Here is an an example: http://jsbin.com/disef/2/edit

```
function ctrl($scope, $sce){
  $scope.aw = function() {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://thisis.the/url");    
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Ilan! This helped, though not enough :( Now I have

    <form method="post" action="https://thisis.the/url" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"> 

but it won't submit.